# Is that a bug in WSS3.0 Web Services queries?

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, filter, wss

I've been struggling all day to debug a query that filters out element based on the Modified field using Lists web service and GetListItems method, to get only the elements modified since the last time I checked.

Here is the query parameter:

```
<Where>
  <Gt>
    <FieldRef Name="Modified" /> 
    <Value Type="DateTime" IncludeTimeValue="TRUE">2010-11-23T17:0:00Z</Value> 
  </Gt>
</Where>
```

I've had trouble figuring out why this returned nothing since one element in the list was clearly modified after this date, specified in UTC. That's because although you specify it in UTC (also enforced in the options parameter), Sharepoint will compare it literally with the modified timestamps stored or displayed with the locale specified in the site settings.

I'm not sure I'm clear, so here's a example:
The site I'm querying is in EST locale, and the latest element has been modified today at 12:11:00, which is 17:12:00Z.

I last checked for updates at 4pm GMT, so my query parameter will contain the following:

```
<Where>
  <Gt>
    <FieldRef Name="Modified" /> 
    <Value Type="DateTime" IncludeTimeValue="TRUE">2010-11-23T16:00:00Z</Value> 
  </Gt>
</Where>
```

And this will not return any value because sharepoint compares 16:00:00Z with 12:11:00 literally and thus has no updates after 16:00:00Z.

I confirmed this by putting 12:10:00Z in the query, and there I get the list element I wanted. Put 12:12:00Z, and it's no more in the results.

So, I guess my question is, is that a bug in WSS 3.0, or am I doing something wrong? If so, how can I do to correct this? BTW, I want to keep my stored times in UTC and cannot control what users do with their sites' settings. Is there a way to retrieve the locale used by the site using web services?

---

**Update:**
See [Is there a way to get a Sharepoint site's locale with web services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265766/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-sharepoint-sites-locale-with-web-services) for the solution.

Comment: Why don't you put your suggestion as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if that's a bug, but I found a workaround here:
[Is there a way to get a Sharepoint site's locale with web services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265766/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-sharepoint-sites-locale-with-web-services)

when you have the offset betwen the site's locale and UTC, just apply the offset to the UTC time you want to filter by and then insert it in you query node.

```
   ndQuery.InnerXml = "<Where><Gt><FieldRef Name='Modified' />" +
   "<Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='TRUE'>" + (last_update + offset).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + " " + (last_update + offset).ToString("HH:mm:ss") + "</Value></Gt></Where>";
```